# Django class based View with 2 post forms returns valid unknown

Tags: python, django, forms

I've got a view in django where post method has 2 different types of form:

```
def post(self, request):
    tweet_form = TweetForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    comment_form = TweetCommentForm(request.POST)
    print(request.POST['form-button'])
    if request.POST['form-button'] == 'add_tweet':
        print(tweet_form.is_valid)
        if tweet_form.is_valid():
            content = tweet_form.cleaned_data['content']
            image = tweet_form.cleaned_data['image']
            tweet = Tweet.objects.create(
                user=request.user,
                content=content,
            )
            if image != None:
                tweet.image = image
            tweet.save()
            return redirect("/home")
    if request.POST['form-button'] == 'add_comment':        
        print(comment_form.is_valid)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            
            content = comment_form.cleaned_data['body']
            return redirect("/home")
        
    ctx = {"tweet_form": tweet_form, "comment_form": comment_form}
    return render(request, "home.html", ctx)
```

The both forms have different name, value, and id.
When i print `(tweet_form.is_valid())` or `(comment_form.is_valid())` i receive sth like:

```
<bound method BaseForm.is_valid of <TweetForm bound=True, valid=Unknown, fields=(content;image)>>
```

Respectively for both forms.
Can i somehow reorganize view to deal with both of forms or i have to have another View?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to print the method instead of evaluating the method.
Try:

```
print(comment_form.is_valid())
print(tweet_form.is_valid())
```

Comment: Ah, you're right. Didn't check it properly. Thanks.